# Karma does not use source maps from Webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-runner

Debugging works well with source maps. But I see that mocha reports errors without using source maps. I use two different approaches: karma-sourcemap-loader, karma-source-map-support'
There is my karma.conf.js

```js
const webpackConfig = require('./testing.webpack.js');
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['ProjectChromeHeadless'],
        basePath: './',
        files: [
            { pattern: 'test/**/*.test.js', watched: false }
        ],
        frameworks: ['should', 'jasmine', 'mocha', 'source-map-support'],
        reporters: ['mocha'],
        preprocessors: {
            'test/**/*.test.js': [
                'webpack'
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-should',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-mocha-reporter',
            'karma-source-map-support'
        ],
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        mochaReporter: {
            showDiff: true
        },
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        customLaunchers: {
            ProjectChromeHeadless: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: ['--disable-translate', '--disable-extensions', '--remote-debugging-port=9223']
            },
            ChromeDebug: {
                base: "Chrome",
                flags: [
                    "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
                ],
                debug: true,
            },
        },
    });

    return config;
};
```

I receive a such output.

```sh
FAILED TESTS:
  Chart
    ✖ expect
      Chrome Headless 87.0.4280.88 (Linux x86_64)
    AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2
    error properties: null({ showDiff: true, actual: 1, expected: 2, constructor: Function, toJSON: Function })
    AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 2
        at UserContext.eval (webpack-internal:///24:2105:15)
        at <Jasmine>
```